# mongodb add objects into array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, express, mern

I'm trying to add elements into an array of objects, but I', having problems with adding more than 1 object.

This is the Model of my groups collection

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name: {type: String, required: true},
password: {type: String, required: true},
description: {type: String, required: true},
scope: String,
groupTeacher: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users',
},
quizzes:[
    {
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        name: String,
        tier: Number,
        category: String,
        questions:[
            {
                _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
                title: String,
                question: String,
                correctAnswer: String,
                answer1: String,
                answer2: String,
                answer3: String,
                answer4: String
            }
        ],
        usersAttempted:[
            {
                _id: {
                    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'users',
                },
                //userEmail: String,
                correctAnswers: Number,
                wrongAnswers: Number,
                answers: [{
                    questionTitle: String,
                    correctAnswer: String,
                    usersAnswer: String
                }]
```

I want to add elements into the 'usersAttempted' array of objects.
I have problems with the 'answers' part. The problem is that there are many questions answers but, I only got it working for adding 1 questions answers.

This is how I did it.

```
    const result = await groupsModel.updateOne({
        "_id": groupId,
        "quizzes._id": quizId,
        "quizzes.usersAttempted._id": {$ne: userId}
    }, 
    {
        $addToSet:{
            "quizzes.$.usersAttempted":{
                _id:userId,
                correctAnswers: questionsCorrect,
                wrongAnswers:   questionsWrong,
                answers:{
                    questionTitle:  answers[0].questionTitle,
                    correctAnswer:  answers[0].correctAnswer,
                    usersAnswer:    answers[0].usersAnswer
                }
            }}});
```

Answers is an array of objects

[image: Answers array of objects]

Thank you for all your help.

EDIT: #1
Small explanation:
I have an array of objects, that I want to add to "usersAttempted" but I have problems with adding more than 1 answer.

EDIT: #2

I managed to add array of objects into the collection, but it is done with indexes.

```
        const result = await groupsModel.updateOne({
        "_id": groupId,
        "quizzes._id": quizId,
        "quizzes.usersAttempted._id": {$ne: userId}
    }, 
    {
        $addToSet:{
            "quizzes.$.usersAttempted":{
                _id:userId,
                correctAnswers: questionsCorrect,
                wrongAnswers:   questionsWrong,
                answers:[{
                    questionTitle:  answers[0].questionTitle,
                    correctAnswer:  answers[0].correctAnswer,
                    usersAnswer:    answers[0].usersAnswer
                },
                {
                    questionTitle:  answers[1].questionTitle,
                    correctAnswer:  answers[1].correctAnswer,
                    usersAnswer:    answers[1].usersAnswer
                },
                {
                    questionTitle:  answers[2].questionTitle,
                    correctAnswer:  answers[2].correctAnswer,
                    usersAnswer:    answers[2].usersAnswer
                }]
                    
            }}});
```

Now I want to find a way of adding an array with x number of objects.

Comment: Why are you only adding a single answer instead of the entire array?

Comment: because I'm not sure how to add the whole array :D Thats why the question

Comment: It would be helpful to post the actual code instead of images of your code. Use the {} button on the toolbar of the editor to designate it as a code block

Comment: I tried to find online how to add an entire array. But I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you try:

```
        $addToSet:{
        "quizzes.$.usersAttempted":{
            _id:userId,
            correctAnswers: questionsCorrect,
            wrongAnswers:   questionsWrong,
            answers                    
        }}});
```

It seems to me that you would be adding the entire answer array...

Comment: Ok, that works. I tried that before but the problem was that the names of fields compared to names in the object were different. Before it was "answers.title" (object) and "questionTitle" (collection). I changed the names so they are the same and it worked perfectly. Thank you. I guess this was your easiest solve :D

Comment: What if I want to update or change the existing value of any field, then how can I do that?